# Asp.NET 4.0 GridView Default Sort Direction & Expression

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, asp.net-4.0, sortdirection

Asp.net 4.0 gridView's built in support for "sort arrows" saves some code. All my grids are sorted by default when they're returned from the database, so it would seem logical that I should indicate which column is *default* sorted on by using the ASP.NET SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass etc.

ASP.NET doesn't decorate the default-sorted column magically: it has no way to know what order the SQL specifies. I can declaratively or programmatically decorate the appropriate header cell with the correct CSS class... but then ASP.NET doesn't remove it for me when I sort. So currently I am stripping this out by traversing the header cells looking for it on first "Sort" event. So I have a bit of code I run twice, once to add the arrow, and once on first manual sort to remove it. That's complicated, almost as much work as doing the whole job was before 4.0.

So... I must be missing something: is there some way to tell an ASP.NET GridView that it's contents are already sorted in a way which avoids having to manually add and then remove that sort indicator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know your Sort Expression & direction You can Setit Explicitly by:

```
GridView.Sort(expression, direction);
```

expression would be list of columns `"col1, col2, etc"`

Comment: Yes, but that instructs the grid to sort itself, does it not? In my case the grid is already sorted, in that the database sorts the stuff before it's bound to the grid. Perhaps I could tell it to sort itself too, which would maybe be a cheap operation as it's already sorted.

Comment: @philw I thought so at first, too.  The part that confused me is that GridView.Sort does not trigger a 2nd data fetch.  It just sets the sort properties that will be used on the next DataBind().  So it's perfectly fine to call GridView.Sort in OnLoad.

Answer (score 1):

To Remove Sorting For particular Column in the GridView which is bounded using AutoGenerateColumn

```
protected void GridView_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    if (GridView.AllowSorting)
    {
        foreach (TableCell tc in GridView.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            if (tc.HasControls())
            {
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)tc.Controls[0];
                if (lb != null && lb.Text.Equals("ColumnName"))
                {                            
                    tc.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```